# Ubuntu 13.04 Purple Screen - Installed ATI Driver

Tags: 13.04, drivers, ati, screen

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. Everything was working fine until i installed some drivers for my Radeon HD 5450. The way i installed those drivers was by going to Ubuntu Software Center and Installing "Additional Drivers" and then installing the ATI driver. Now when i boot up ubuntu, the Grub screen comes up fine but after it a purple screen comes and it freezes there and then a black screen and it hangs there. I can't see anything after the purple screen since my LCD gives "No Signal". I tried putting "nomodeset" for gfx mode and in place of quiet splash, but it still gives me "No Signal" though i hear a Drum sound. I also tried going to Recovery mode but my LCD doesn't recognize the resolution and gives me "No Signal" so i cant see the list of recovery options.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.